# why not able to find web page element by id using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

try to play with Selenium, created a very simple example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver())
            {

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://gmail.com");

                IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.00));
                wait.Until(d => ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Email")));

                Console.WriteLine("Page loaded ...");

                IWebElement userNameElt = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));

                while (!userNameElt.Displayed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Page not finished loading yet ...");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }


                userNameElt.SendKeys("my@sample.com");
                userNameElt.Submit();

                IWebElement passwordElt = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Passwd"));
                userNameElt.SendKeys("password");
                userNameElt.Submit();

                IWebElement submitBtnElt = driver.FindElement(By.Id("signIn"));
                submitBtnElt.Click();
            }
        }
```

but it complain not able to find element

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.25.3.0 
Listening on port 1423 
Page loaded ...

Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == Email
```

any idea?

Comment: What about another elements? Try to wait for and find Passwd instead of Email.

Comment: What about other drivers? See if it's related to just IE or not.

Comment: user firefoxdrive, I am able to fill the username, but get "page might change" exception when try to populate password..

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind reading through your example.

First, depending on your network, the timeout for the Wait may be too short. Two seconds may not be long enough. Bump that up to ten and see if it's more stable.

Secondly, drop the lambda-fu from your waits. It's incorrect, and all you need is a simple

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Email")));
```

Also, keep in mind that your manual while (!userNameElt.Displayed) loop doesn't make sense. You've already got a wait for that element above, so this loop shouldn't ever come in to play.

Finally, you don't need to Submit() to the elements after using SendKeys().

Here's a refactored block of code that's stable and does the trick.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://gmail.com");

    IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.00));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Email")));

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys("mysample.com");

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Passwd")));
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Passwd")).SendKeys("password");

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("signIn")).Click();
}
```